# Problems With Using Dispatch Queue in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to use dispatch queue so I can wait for one portion of code to finish before continuing onto the second portion. Below is my code, I would like for the code within the dispatch_sync to execute and complete before the code in dispatch_barrier_async. I have looked around trying to figure out why this doesn't work to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

```
__block dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.myQueueForMaps", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_sync(queue, ^{

    for(XYZToDoItem* item in toDoItems){

        MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = item.itemName;
        // somehow deal with radius
        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1);
        request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(currentLoc.coordinate, span);

        MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:request];
        [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error){
            int i = 0;
            double minimum = INFINITY;
            MKMapItem *closest;

            for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {

                UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50 + 20*i, 300, 200)];
                myLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

                NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", item.name, item.phoneNumber];
                myLabel.text = myString;

                CLLocation *loc = item.placemark.location;
                CLLocationDistance dist = [currentLoc distanceFromLocation:loc];

                if (dist < minimum) {
                    minimum = dist;
                    closest = item;
                }
                //NSLog(@"%@", closest.name);
                //NSLog(@"dist %f", minimum);
            }

            if (minimum < item.radius) {
                NSLog(@"match %@", closest.name);
                item.closeMatch = closest;
                item.match = true;
            }
            else {
                item.match = false;
                item.closeMatch = nil;
            }
        }];
    }
});

dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{
    [findMatches notifyNearbyTasks];
});
```

Comment: It's possible that you want a dispatch group. Check out the section titled "Waiting on Groups of Queued Tasks" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: Also, do you mean to call `dispatch_sync` on the first queue, then call `dispatch_barrier_async`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your `dispatch_sync()` block should indeed finish executing before your barrier block. The same isn't true for the code in the completion block that you pass to `-[MKLocalSearch startWithCompletionHandler:]`, however. `-startWithCompletionHandler:` is an asynchronous method, and there's a good chance that the search won't complete before the end of the block in which you start it.

Note that the completion block runs on the main thread -- from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKLocalSearch/startWithCompletionHandler%3a):

> The provided completion handler is always executed on your app’s main thread.

That is, the completion block won't be scheduled on your `queue`, but on the main dispatch queue instead. So, even if the completion block were scheduled before your synchronous block completes, it would be scheduled on a different dispatch queue and wouldn't prevent the barrier block from starting.

It looks like your goal is to delay the call to `[findMatches notifyNearbyTasks]` until all the searches have completed. One way to do that might be to add each search to a list, and have the completion block check remove the search from the list, check the size of the list, and make the appropriate call when the list is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do something like what you suggested. Thanks for the help.